# How to display Edit Button only for last insertion Row of specific customer using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

See image of records

[image]

thanx in advance In a table I have multiple customer records. I want to display edit button only for last row of specific customer. That means if customer is repeating in table, his last record should have edit button. How i can do that using javascript? i tried the methods below using controller it worked but it was not good becuse i have some roles in my table and that cause issues i want javascript? where i pass my customer id in javascript and check if id repeats edit disply button to last record of that customer

Here you can see total point is a repeating customer. On his last row should be editable & Hafiz M. Tazeem is not repeating - he should also have edit button

```
 @foreach($orders as $order)
          <tr>
            <input type="hidden" class="ot_id" name="ot_id" value="{{ $order->ordertaker->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" class="area_id" name="area_id" value="{{ $order->customers->area_id }}">
            <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->customers->user->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->ordertaker->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->unit }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->subtotal }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->received_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->amount - $order->received_amount  }}</td>
            @if($order->received_amount > ($order->subtotal + $order->amount_left - $order->advance))
              <td>$order->amount_left</td>
            @else
              <td>{{ $order->advance }}</td>
            @endif

            <td>{{ $order->c_benefit }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->customers->location_url }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->created_at }}</td>
            <td>
             @if(Auth::user()->role <= 3)
              <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="confirm-to[]" value="{{ $order->id }}" class="approve-to" />
              </label>
              @endif
              @if(Auth::user()->role <= 3 || Auth::user()->role == 5)
                <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#order-detail-popup" class="btn btn-sm btn-success view-details" id="{{ $order->id }}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>

                <a href="{{ route('edit.order' , $order->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="{{ route('delete.order' , $order->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
              @endif
            </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach[][1]
```

Comment: You can use IF stm check if specif user have attribute(like if is admin do) and add row based to result.

Comment: You can add a flag in your table of customers (where the records of the image come from) then before inserting a new record of a customer you have to update that flag to false and for the new inserted one the flag should be true you can use a query like this one `DB::statement("UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET can_update = false where customer_id = ".$id." AND can_update=true);` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a second variable = `::select('customers')` and remplace $record->customers by the variable , and after that use:

```
$numItems = count($cust);
$i = 0;
foreach($cust as $key=>$c) {
  if(++$i === $numItems) {
    echo 'a href= ....';
  }
}
```